# Prime gaps that are "relatively" bigger than all later prime gaps: Is this in OEIS?

Tags: reference-request, prime-numbers, oeis, prime-gaps

[This OEIS entry](https://oeis.org/A002386) is about

> Primes (lower end) with record gaps to the next consecutive prime: primes p(k) where p(k+1) - p(k) exceeds p(j+1) - p(j) for all j < k.

I'm wondering about a different kind of "record gap": primes $p(k)$ for which $\dfrac{p(k+1)-p(k)}{p(k)}$ exceeds the corresponding value, not for all smaller indices than $k$ but for all larger ones. For example, if I'm not mistaken, $\dfrac{127-113}{113}\approx 0.1238938$ is larger than the corresponding quantity for all later (not earlier) prime gaps. I suspect the same is true of $\dfrac{1361-1327}{1327}\approx 0.0256217.$

Is this in OEIS somewhere?

Comment: https://oeis.org/A111943 gives "Prime $p$ with prime gap $q - p$ of $n$-th record Cramer-Shanks-Granville ratio, where $q$ is smallest prime larger than $p$ and C-S-G ratio is $(q-p)/(\log p)^2$".

Comment: https://oeis.org/A111870 is "Prime $p$ with prime gap $q - p$ of $n$-th record merit, where $q$ is smallest prime larger than $p$ and the merit of a prime gap is $(q-p)/\log(p)$."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[oeis.org/A209407](https://oeis.org/A209407) is the smaller prime in those gaps, and [oeis.org/A277718](https://oeis.org/A277718) is the larger prime. The gaps themselves do not appear to be on OEIS.

Comment: As I had guessed, $1327$ is there.

Comment: OEIS says $p(i+1)/p(i)$ is bigger than in all later cases; I said $\big( p(i+1)-p(i)\big)/p(i)$ is bigger than in all later cases. These are trivially equivalent, but I think I could cogently argue that my way of looking at it is better.

Comment: @MichaelHardy You might add that as a comment in the OEIS!